# Xamarin.Android: Changing a specific value in a list during runtime

Tags: list, listview, xamarin.android, listadapter

I have a simple Xamarin.Android-App.

On the Activity of this app, there is a list displayed. Please see following MyActivity.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android        ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation  ="vertical"
android:layout_width ="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:layout_width ="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text         ="Click Me"
    android:layout_marginTop   ="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft   ="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight   ="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/space" />
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

One row of this list contains simply two entries, please see ListRow.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
android:orientation="horizontal"     
android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
android:layout_height="fill_parent">        
    <TextView             
        android:id="@+id/name"            
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"          
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft  ="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop   ="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight ="5dp" />
    <TextView             
        android:id="@+id/value"            
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft  ="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop   ="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight ="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So the code-behind of that activity looks like the following:

```
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    List<Entry> List = null;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyActivity);

        List = PopulateList();
        var lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list);
        var adapter = new ListAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.List, List);
        lv.Adapter = adapter;

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button).Click += OnButtonClick;
    }
}
```

For the sake of completeness, here is the code for my ListAdapter.cs-class:

```
class ListAdapter : ArrayAdapter
{
    List<Entry> List;
    public ListAdapter(Context Context, int ListId, List<Entry> List) : base(Context, ListId, List)
    {
        this.List = List;
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return List.Count; }
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.List, parent, false);
        }
        v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.name).Text = List[position].Name;
        v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.value).Text = "Original Value";
        return v;
    }
}
```

So my question now is the following: Assuming that there is more than one item within that List. On click of the button, I want to change one specific text within that list. Let's say of the second entry in the list the (Resource.Id.value).Text (which now says "Original Value") to "Changed Value" or something like that. But only of the second one. All the other items should stay the same.

Please see following example of output aimed, maybe it's easier to understand what I am trying to do:

Name  Value
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
No.1    Original Value
No.2    Original Value
No.3    Original Value

[Button Click]

Name  Value
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
No.1    Original Value
No.2    Changed Value
No.3    Original Value

Can anyone maybe help me / tell me how to do this? What does my `private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)`-method have to look like? How can I access a single entry in that list?

Thanks in advance for all answers and best regards

Comment: If your button is outside of the listview, can you get an indication such as which position Item needs to change when you click on a Clicked event ? If can,you could define a method in the adapter, click on the button to pass position through the adapter, and then refresh the data to change the value of that item .
or you could add a button to each listitem ，then click button to change the corresponding item's value

Comment: Hello @LeoZhu and thank you really much for your helping efforts.
As trying to show in the two tables above, in this example the position of the item which needs to change is `int positionToChange = 1;` (starting to count with 0). Not the first item, not the last item, only the second one. How can I pass the position through the adapter?

Comment: do you mean to change the value of the second item forever after clicking the button？

Comment: Yes. At least for now.

Answer (score 1):

you could add a method in adapter to `notifyDataSetChanged();` :

```
class ListAdapter : ArrayAdapter
    {
      List<Entry> List;
      private int ItemPositionToChange = -1;
      public ListAdapter(Context Context, int ListId, List<Entry> List) : 
          base(Context, ListId, List)
        {
          this.List = List;
        }

      //this method to let adapter notify
      public void ChangeItemValue(int position)
        {
            ItemPositionToChange = position;
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

      public override int Count
        {
          get { return List.Count; }
        }
      public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
          View v = convertView;
          if (v == null)
            {
              LayoutInflater inflater = 
             (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
              v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.List, parent, false);
            }
              v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.name).Text = List[position].Name;

              //change the item value according to your needs
              if(position == ItemPositionToChange ){
                v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.value).Text = "Changed Value";
              }else{
                v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.value).Text = "Original Value";
              }

              return v;
           }
    }
```

then in your button click listener :

```
void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //positionToChange is which item you want to change
       adapter.ChangeItemValue(positionToChange);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the Entry class, but it seems to have a Text property.

Assuming you know the index of the string (myIndex below):

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    List[myIndex].Text = "Changed Value";
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Hello James and thank you so much for your answer. I am pretty sure that we need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in the end, but unfortunately the entry class has no text property (or at least I do not know how to access it). If I do `private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e){FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.pinTextView).Text = "Changed Value";}` only the first item changes (not the second one as exemplary expected). If I add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` this stops and nothing is happening anymore when clicking the button.

Comment: You don't want to be editing the TextView text in OnButtonClick. The point of the adapter is to manage the interaction between your view and your List<Entry>. ListAdapter holds a reference to this data, which is what you should be updating. The reason nothing happens after clicking is because you didn't change the data in List.

Is it this Entry class you're using?:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry

Here's my activity code, with a List<string> instead of List<Entry>, which should give you an idea : https://pastebin.com/3XZ1MDh4